# C++ LuDecomposer.mpi.exe ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000005

Tags: c++, mpi

i'm new in mpi, when i try to run my code i get this error.

PS C:\Users\dhaua\source\repos\LuDecomposer.mpi\Debug> mpiexec .\LuDecomposer.mpi.exe

job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0-1] terminated

[2] process exited without calling finalize

[3] terminated

---- error analysis -----

[2] on DESKTOP-0U5JD54
.\LuDecomposer.mpi.exe ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000005

---- error analysis -----

main.cpp:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "LuDecomposer.h"
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "LuTests.h"
#include "mpi.h"
//#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    int thread_rank, thread_size, processor_name_length;
    int* thread_range;
    double cpu_time_start, cpu_time_fini;
    char* processor_name = new char[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME * sizeof(char)];
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &thread_size);

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &thread_rank);

    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    LuDecomposer decomposer(thread_size, thread_rank);
    LuTests tests(&decomposer);

    if (thread_rank == 0) { printf("============= Runing tests\n"); };

    printf("=============MaltiplicationTestTwo\n");
    tests.MaltiplicationTestTwo(thread_size, thread_rank);
    
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

TestLy.cpp:

```
void LuTests::MaltiplicationTestTwo(int thread_size, int thread_rank)
{
    double A[] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 2, 0,
        0, 0, 3, 4, 0,
        0, 0, 5, 6, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };

    double B[] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 3, 5,
        0, 0, 2, 4, 6,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };

    double expectedAA[] = {
        5, 11, 17,
        11, 25, 39,
        17, 39, 61
    };

    double* AA = new double[9]();

    decomposer->Multiplication(A, B, AA, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2);
    if (thread_rank == 0) {
        bool isCorrect = decomposer->AreEqual(AA, expectedAA, 3);

        if (isCorrect)
            printf("============= Success!\n");
        else
        {
            printf("============= Error!\n");
            printf("============= Print AA\n");
            decomposer->PrintMatrix(AA, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

LuDecomposer.cpp:

```
void LuDecomposer::Multiplication(double* A, double* B, double* Res, int size, int subMatrixHeight, int subMatrixWidth, int rowBiasA, int colBiasA, int rowBiasB, int colBiasB)
{
    int u, v, p;
    
    MPI_Status status;
        int* range = new int[2];
        if (thread_rank == 0)
        {
            interval[0] = 0;
            interval[1] = subMatrixHeight;

            

            cpu_time_start = MPI_Wtime();
        }
        MPI_Bcast(&interval, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        
            range = get_interval(thread_rank, thread_size, interval);


            for (range[0]; range[0] < range[1]; range[0]++)
            {
                u = (range[0] + rowBiasA) * size + colBiasA;
                for (int j = 0; j < subMatrixWidth; j++)
                {
                    v = (j + rowBiasB) * size + colBiasB;
                    p = u + j;

                    for (int t = 0; t < subMatrixHeight; t++)
                    {
                        Res[range[0] * subMatrixHeight + t] += A[p] * B[v + t];
                    }
                }
            }
            if (thread_rank == 0)
        {
            cpu_time_fini = MPI_Wtime();
    //      printf("CPU Time: %lf ms\n", (cpu_time_fini - cpu_time_start) * 1000);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I strongly doubt your code even compiles...

Comment: it's not a full code, but a function that a want to be a parallel. I run that with omp and that works perfect, but i cant write it with mpi.

Comment: Format the error using code formatting for readability.